# Show answers to current question in the "Close Vote" queue

Tags: feature-request

When a question in the Close Votes has any duplicate votes against it, there are tabs where you can see the nominated duplicates. This is great, because it lets me have a closer look at them before deciding if I want to vote to close as duplicate.

However, for questions that have votes against it to close as "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error" I would very much like to be able to see any answer(s) inline as well. Especially if there is an accepted one.
I might **suspect** that the question was caused by a typo but being able to see the (often accepted) answer that points out the typo would make me much more confident in my vote.

Comment: I often right-click on the question's title and select "open in a new tab". Then I can view the whole Q&A without disturbing the browser tab with the review.

Comment: Question: what if an answer is not accepted and there are 15 answers there? Which one (if any) would you want to see in this case? I think most of the "typographical error" questions get solved through comments anyway..

Comment: @AdrianHHH I rarely have less than 15 open work-related tabs, I really don't like having to open new ones.

Comment: @mehow That's a good point, maybe showing the accepted answer if there are one? I came across two cases of typo errors being resolved in the answer just today, but I agree that they often are resolved in comments. I'm suggesting a tab for opening the answers/accepted answer here, not polluting the "main" question window with the answer(s).